# MS Word VBA How to Search and copy selected text to beginning of the Paragraph

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

I want to search and copy year specified in the paragraph and copy it to beginning of the paragraph. following is the code i am working with, it does selects the year but doesn't copy it to the beginning:

```
Sub CopyYeartoFirst()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
'    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
With ActiveDocument.Content
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "[0-9]{4}"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Execute
    End With
While .Find.Found = True

    Selection.Copy
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
    Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdPasteDefault)
    'Selection.TypeText Text:=" -- "
    .Find.Execute

    'Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Wend


End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use something like this before pasting your search results

```
Dim oRng As Range
Set oRng = Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range
oRng.Collapse wdCollapseStart
oRng.Select
```